# Is quantum cloning $|\psi\rangle|\psi_1\rangle|\psi_2\rangle|C\rangle\to e^{i\alpha}|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle|C'\rangle$ prohibited?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra, unitarity

I think the no-cloning theorem is too restrictive, as in,

$$|\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle\to e^{i\alpha}|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle \tag{1}$$

does not allow for any arbitrariness in the final state.

Instead, suppose we have three particles in initial states $|\psi \rangle$, $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$,  and we have an external quantum system (called a cloner) in an initial state $|C\rangle$. The four are not mutually isolated. They can interact. We consider the cloning:

$$|\psi\rangle|\psi_1\rangle|\psi_2\rangle |C\rangle \to e^{i\alpha} |\phi \rangle |\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle |C'\rangle$$

We isolated the four components in the end. This gives us two copies of the state $|\psi\rangle$ and we get two arbitrary states $|\phi\rangle$ and $|C'\rangle$ that we don't care about.

The states of all four components of the system change in the process. In $(1) $, the state of the first particle remained unaffected, which is too much to ask for from an interaction process.

My question, **is this type of cloning theoretically proven to be prohibited too?**

Comment: The normal proof for the no-cloning theorem applies to your example, because what you wrote are product states, and therefore we can just factor out the auxiliary systems, and then you are left with normal cloning. The fact that you moved the state from one subspace to another doesn't matter, you can swap them back. The closest thing to cloning you can do is: a|0>+b|1> -> a|0,0> + b|1,1>.

Comment: @fulis I don't think the normal proof applies here. You can't factor out the auxiliarly states because they're coupled to the other states. They aren't evolving indepdendently. The unitary evolution matrices can't be factored as only the combined system has a unitary evolution. The sub-systems don't.

Comment: See [Ruben Verresen's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/297053/50583) to a similar question of mine for a proof that quantum no-cloning holds even in the presence of a copier. Your particular proposed map is strictly speaking *not* a cloning operation but merely a "doubling" - it destroys the original state into $\lvert \phi\rangle$, after all.

Comment: What's the point of having more than one extra auxiliary system? I'd say the most general version should be as in [Problem 6c here](https://schuch.univie.ac.at/fileadmin/user_upload/a_schuch/teaching/ws22-qi/ws22-qi-exercise-02.pdf), i.e. $|\psi\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle \mapsto |\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle|a_\psi\rangle$. This should subsume all cases.

Comment: @fulis This is not true if the ancillas on the rhs depend on the state to be cloned.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Why is this not a cloner? You are merely swapping the systems. It takes one psi and gives you two. That's the definition of a cloner.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch you're right, but if the ancilla is state dependent then the problem essentially reduces to cloning into the ancilla as well, which is what you showed in your answer.

Comment: @fulis This is true, but it needs to be shown. (And there is no need that the ancilla is a "nice" clone. But agreed: If it contains any information about the state, it only makes the cloning worse, not better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of your question seems: Can we build a cloner if we allow for some extra quantum system in the output, i.e. a linear operation which does
$$
\lvert \psi\rangle\mapsto \lvert \psi\rangle\lvert \psi\rangle\lvert a_\psi\rangle\ ,
\tag{1}
$$
where $\lvert a_\psi\rangle$ is an ancilla which can depend on $\psi$, and which we trace out. (Such an operation could involve adding ancillas on the l.h.s.)

We can now follow precisely the normal argument, i.e. use linearity (using qubits):
$$
\begin{align}
\lvert 0\rangle & \mapsto \lvert 0\rangle\lvert 0\rangle\lvert a_0\rangle
\\
\lvert 1\rangle & \mapsto \lvert 1\rangle\lvert 1\rangle\lvert a_1\rangle\ .
\end{align}
\tag{2}
$$
Applying the cloner to $\lvert0\rangle+\lvert 1\rangle$ gives on the one hand (from (1))
$$
\lvert 0\rangle\lvert 0\rangle\lvert a_+\rangle
+\lvert 0\rangle\lvert 1\rangle\lvert a_+\rangle
+\lvert 1\rangle\lvert 0\rangle\lvert a_+\rangle
+\lvert 1\rangle\lvert 1\rangle\lvert a_+\rangle
$$
and on the other hand (from (2))
$$
\lvert 0\rangle\lvert 0\rangle\lvert a_0\rangle
+\lvert 1\rangle\lvert 1\rangle\lvert a_1\rangle\ .
$$
You will notice that the first expression has terms of the form
$\lvert 0\rangle\lvert 1\rangle\lvert \mathrm{stuff}\rangle$, while the second one doesn't. These terms cannot come from anything in the $\lvert\mathrm{stuff}\rangle$ register, since they are simply not contained in the span of $\lvert 0\rangle\lvert 0\rangle\lvert a_0\rangle$ and $\lvert 1\rangle\lvert 1\rangle\lvert a_1\rangle$.

Thus, the two expressions cannot be equal, regardless of what $\lvert a_\psi\rangle$ is (or what its dimension is), and thus, a linear cloning map of this form cannot exist.

Note that by Stinespring dilation, this also implies that there cannot be a completely positive $\mathcal E$ map which clones,
$$
\mathcal E(\lvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert) = 
\lvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert\otimes
\lvert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert\ .
$$